# Server doesn't recive HTTP request

Tags: android, react-native, asp.net-core, android-emulator

I'm having trouble with fetching to the server.

I'm working with react-native on android emulator, and the web api is on asp.net core. The two currently are local, react-native works on port 8081 and the server on port 8647.

This is the url i tried on postman and works : 'http://localhost:8647/api/convention/b1538ce0-e152-4eca-88b8-d0c02dab7e5a/details'

The fetch from the aplication dont get to the server.
i had tried with changing local host to 10.0.2.2 , my IPv4 addres and it still dont get to the server.

Im using the same fetch function that i use on a portal that works with the server ( it works on port 8080).

I added this bind right after the original bind  to the applicationhost.config of the server

I'm trying to understand the problem , and i didn't found a answer for it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Internet permissions in the manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```